# Manage reference of multiple _com_ptr_t instances

Tags: c++, com

I'm building a VC++ dll that exposes the functionality of some Hardware by its driver dll which uses COM Objects. The driver object (COMDriver) is a _com_ptr_t which encapsulates the interface that has all the hardware functions. My VC++ code exposes its functions using JNI to be used by a Java application upper in the stack,  but it has been a pain managing the objects lifetime using COM and JNI together, as I'm not the most experienced COM guy...

In the Java client, I have up to 3 threads that handle the communication to each own device. They call the VC++ dll in order to send the commands to each device.

On the VC++ dll, I want to be able to create several instances of the driver _com_ptr_t via a JNI call (let's call it openConnection) and store them in a global map that matches the JNIEnv pointer address (that maps out to the calling Java thread) to the respective driver instance (the _com_ptr_t instance), something like this:

```
//Maps the caller Java Thread (by JNIEnv*) to the respective driver instance.
unordered_map<uintptr_t, ICOMDriverPtr> stateMap;

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_openConnection(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj){


    //This pointer is a reference to the Handler Thread that calls openConnection
    uintptr_t env_addresss = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(env);
  
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);

    try
    {
    ICOMDriverPtr spDriver;
        // Create an instance of the driver.
    spDriver.CreateInstance(__uuidof(COMDriver));

       //do driver stuff....

       //store the mapping of JNIEnv and the driver COM smart pointer 
       stateMap[env_addresss] = spDriver;
    } 
    catch { //error handling
```

When I make a call to this driver after initializing it via another JNI call I was doing  `ICOMDriverPtr spDriver = stateMap[env_addresss];` but I have a COM error saying Invalid pointer to this newly created spDriver.

I tried working around GetInterfacePtr and tried multiple & and * operators with problems on compilation. in runtime this is what worked but still can't get a valid reference to the previously created spDriver.

From the Microsoft documentation on the _com_ptr_t class, the = operator should create a copy of the smart pointer stored in the map (on the second call). Should I detach the smart pointer on the OpenConnection call? (because I think it might be releasing the pointer after the JNI scope ends on the open connection, but I'm not sure). If someone could shed a light on how to copy and reference the COMDriver around JNI I would be much grateful, Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the env_address is the same in every call?

Comment: Yes, I have logged the calls to a file, and for the same thread it is the same env_address.

Comment: and what happens if you store the pointer in the map and then get the pointer from the map inside the same JNI call? or without JNI?

Comment: What is the error *exactly*?

Comment: Just tried inside the same JNI call, still get the same Invalid Pointer error (Simon the error is E_POINTER  which is HRESULT = 0x80004003). I think that any of the = or & parameters just copy the reference of the pointer, and not make a deep copy that holds the state of the COM object.

Comment: In your actual code, do you by any chance have `CoUninitialize` matching the `CoInitialize` shown? That would release all COM objects created in this apartment.

Comment: Igor, the CoUninitialize is called by a separate JNI function that is to be used after all the connections are closed, I'm not using it on the openConnection.

Comment: @RicardoPedrosa The copy constructor calls AddRef on the underlying pointer for you, so you do not need to worry about that.

Comment: ICOMDriverPtr is a typedef to `_com_ptr_t<COMDriver>`?

Comment: @Botje thank you, yes the AddRef adds up to the count in the copy constructor, but somehow I think the "=" is not creating a valid object with the same state of the original spDriver object. I tried logging the address of the instance in between JNI calls, and it is pointing to the same memory address but still when I try to access any object properties of the copied instance (that is in the map) it gives the E_POINTER error always... I guess it might have some <unique_ptr> implementation in the background....

Comment: @Botje yes ICOMDriverPtr is the _com_ptr_t<COMDriver> interface wrapper, with the CLSID in the system registry.

Comment: I really doubt that the = operator is to blame. The documentation of [`operator=`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/um/comip.h#L250-L255) does a proper `AddRef`. Please edit your code with the calling code. Additionally, since it also errors if you do it in the same function, JNI has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Threading is not a subtle detail in writing COM code.  Interface pointers usually need to be marshaled when used in another thread, required so the COM runtime can keep the library usage thread-safe.  Unless you declare the COM server as free-threaded, not typically a good idea.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/creating-the-global-interface-table

Comment: yes @Botje, JNI in principle had nothing to do with the issue. In the same JNI scope (which preserves the scope and doesn't GC any variable) the map allocation and access would also fail. My guess is that the driver source code must had any `unique_ptr` implementation that would prevent copying the variable pointed. 

I changed the behaviour of the application to be stateless... any call to the driver by any thread will open and close its driver instance. At the time it is not giving any fault behaviour, but if it does in the future, i'll make the app as a socket COM server. Thank you all!

Comment: The driver has no say in what you do with pointers it gives out. However, one scenario I can imagine is that its `QueryInterface` method does not properly call `AddRef`, which would cause the errors you mention when `Release` is called down the line (eg when your `spDriver` goes out of scope).